# How to get max upload size and accepted file types on multisite?

Tags: multisite, uploads, limit

I'm switching a single WordPress site to a WordPress Multisite. I'm maintaining some post meta boxes with custom fields, and some front-end forms, where I maintained some features like maximum upload size for media library uploads, and restricted to some specific file types, using some third party plugins.

While switching to multisite, I noticed that the features are implemented by core per blog. I loved that. As it's functioning properly, I need to get those value from database, so that I can warn my users about the accepted file types and maximum upload limit per file in a tooltip or in an instruction field.

I know I can do this easily using `$wpdb`, but is there any default functions, that can facilitate me fetching the data easily?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can easily grab those multisite values from database using an MU (`μ`) Function: [`get_site_option()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/WPMU_Functions/get_site_option)

### Getting Fields

#### Maximum Upload Size

The maximum upload size, per site (**NOT** per blog), per file can be found using:

```
$max_up = get_site_option('fileupload_maxk');
var_dump($max_up); //in kilobytes
```

#### Accepted File Types

The accepted file types per site (**NOT** per blog) can be found using:

```
$aft = get_site_option('upload_filetypes');
var_dump($aft); //space separated values

//values in an array :)
$aft_array = explode( ' ', $aft );
var_dump($aft);
```

### Under the hood

The values are stored in WordPress multisite database, in `sitemeta` (can be `wp_sitemeta`) table, just like any other meta table, using a `meta_id`, `meta_key` and `meta_value`. But as it's site specific (**NOT** blog specific), so the `site_id` is also stored.

Why `site_id`? Please refer to the `#3` link of References.

### References:

1. [MU (μ) Functions](https://codex.wordpress.org/Category:WPMU_Functions) - WordPress Codex
2. [`get_site_option()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/WPMU_Functions/get_site_option) - WordPress Codex - for additional `$key`s
3. [Wordpress: difference between site_id and blog_id?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4189358/1743124) - StackOverflow